# Use class from vendor module in custom controller

Tags: magento2, controllers, backend, pdf

I'm trying to call a 'new FPDF()' in my custom controller, i keep getting the following error:

Uncaught Error: Class 'setasign\fpdf\FPDF' not found in ../app/code/Forza/catalogPrintPdf/Controller/category/pdf.php

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<?php

  namespace Forza\catalogPrintPdf\Controller\category;

  use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
  use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
  use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
  use Forza\catalogPrintPdf\Model\ProductCollection;
  use setasign\fpdf\fpdf;

  class pdf extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
  {
     protected $pageFactory;
     protected $resultJsonFactory;
     protected $productCollection;


    public function __construct(
      Context $context,
      PageFactory $pageFactory,
      JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
      ProductCollection $ProductCollection

   )
  {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    $this->productCollection = $ProductCollection;

  }



   public function execute() {

     $pdf  = new FPDF();
     $this->fpdf->addPage('hello');
     $this->fpdf->Output();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed in the execute function

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
```

to

```
$pdf = new \FPDF();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the fpdf into __contruct function.

After injection run the following command.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I fixed it by instead of $pdf = new FPDF(); I used $pdf = new \FPDF(); when I injected it into my constructor it wasn't working

Comment: ok. So its working now thats the great thing. But the right way is to inject the class and working accordingly.